# Sharing large files

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, socket.io

I have to develop a file sharing system using node.js and I'm not sure how should I send large files between my users.

Right now I have a simple node.js + express + socket.io server that detects connections and allows the user to interchange small files by just doing:

`socket.emit('file', selectedFile);`

where `selectedFile` is a `File` object that comes from a regular `<input type="file">`

As I said, this is working for small files but I'm not sure how should I implement something that works for larger files. Right now when I try to send something bigger the user sending the file gets disconnected. Any hints?

Comment: You're most likely going to have to chunk it up and send it in parts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it

**Client Side**

1. Open file as stream
2. Create chunks of a specific size (e.g. 10kb)
3. Attach an index to each chunk and send to server
4. Record acknowledgement of each index from the server
5. If connection is broken, simply start resending file chunks from last acknowledged index
6. Repeat until file is completely streamed

**Server Side**

1. Receive chunk from client
2. Store chunk in temporary file
3. Send receipt acknowledgement to client
4. Once all chunks are received, assemble in correct order and convert to appropriate encoding scheme